# Jboss failover testing

Tags: windows, jboss, failover

I have a peculiar situation here. I have installed JBoss 5.1.0 as a service in Wintel box.
The service will restart itself if the JBoss instance fails.

However I could not find a way to test this scenario. I killed the JVM that was running the JBoss, but it did not restart the service. I need to make the JBoss service end abnormally so that I can ensure it is restarts again.

In a nutsehll, I need a way to make JBoss end abnormally.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Write a JSP that calls `System.exit(1)`? That might fall foul of the Security Manager, though, and JBoss might not permit it.

In my experience, JBoss nodes (and app servers in general) tend not to crash in such a way as the process exists. Instead, they're more likely to consume increasing resources (e.g. memory) until they stop responding, and need explicit restarting. That's certainly easier to reproduce, but it's harder to handle automatically.